# Does Assurance literally forgo a roll and thus prevent effects that require a roll?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

Here's what [Assurance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=756) has to say:

> Even in the worst circumstances, you can perform basic tasks. Choose a
> skill you’re trained in. **You can forgo rolling a skill check for that
> skill to instead receive a result of 10 + your proficiency bonus (do
> not apply any other bonuses, penalties, or modifiers).**

If Assurance literally forgoes a roll, does this mean effects that are based on a roll result do not work with Assurance?

At first glance, I assumed Assurance simply replaces your roll result with 10 + your proficiency bonus. You don't roll but have a roll result nonetheless to determine success. For example, I was always under the impression that 'rolling a success' was equivalent to 'get a success' or 'succeeding at a check.' Now I'm wondering if there's actually a difference and the omission of the word 'roll' could be significant in some effects.

Most effects mention a roll or rolling like [Assured Identification](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2111):

> You rarely misidentify an item. When using Arcana, Nature, Occultism,
> or Religion checks to Identify Magic, **if you roll a critical failure**,
> you get a failure instead. If you would misidentify a cursed item
> because **you roll a success** but not a critical success, you simply
> can't identify it instead.

Some do not mention rolls at all like [Dubious Knowledge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=776):

> You're a treasure trove of information, but not all of it comes from
> reputable sources. **When you fail** (but don't critically fail) a Recall
> Knowledge check using any skill, you learn a bit of true knowledge and
> a bit of erroneous knowledge, but you don't have any way to
> differentiate which is which.

Comment: Is this question titled right? It seems obvious that assurance forgoes a roll, but the bulk of the question is about how that interacts with other rules

Comment: @Lovell I changed the title to hopefully reflect that difference better

Comment: @SheepStyle welcome to RPG.SE! Excellent first question! Be sure to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Forgo isn't the best word choice, Assurance works as rolling

The clear intent of Assurance is that you no longer have to actually roll a die, but the results should be adjudicated *as though you had*. Anything that references "rolling a success" or similar is functionally the same as "getting a success" and Assurance affects either.

Normally I would take words at their face value, but we have to remember that Paizo has a number of writers and has adopted a stance that things don't have to be written exactly the same to mean the same thing (vis-à-vis "rolling" vs "getting"). And we know that Assurance is still a type of *roll* because it's a [Fortune](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=76) effect.

> **A fortune effect beneficially alters how you roll your dice.** You can never have more than one fortune effect alter a single roll. If multiple fortune effects would apply, you have to pick which to use. If a fortune effect and a misfortune effect would apply to the same roll, the two cancel each other out, and you roll normally.

A fun side effect of this is that Assurance can be negated with a [Misfortune](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=110) effect and vice versa; if you have a Misfortune effect on you, you can use Assurance to roll normally.

Because Assurance is still a *type of roll* (even if there is no physical/digital rolling of a die), it qualifies for any text referencing rolling a [result] (assuming 10+proficiency is enough to succeed).

Comment: Assurance can be used to negate a Misfortune effect? Wow. I've been playing this game since it basically came out and never noticed that Assurance had the Fortune trait. Definitely an understated benefit, although Misfortune is quite rare.

Comment: Yeah the interaction is particularly strange because it means you end rolling a die. You can still pass/fail but you don't have that pesky double chance to fail.

Comment: @Ifusaso misfortune effect has you rolling twice, assurance has you rolling no times, they cancel each other out and you roll once.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: I'm not saying it should do anything else. But usually the (Mis)Fortune interaction stops you from rolling two dice positively or negatively because most Fortune effects are rerolls or rolling twice for the better result. AFAIK, Assurance is the only way to not roll a die for a check, at the moment, so it's position is kind of unique.